# How to host deploy my django project to firebase

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I made this little django project, it shows weather of next three days of given city, its just a single page project, it looks like this
[image]

i want to deploy/host it on firebase
my project link [here](https://github.com/dexterpuru/weatherapp)
But i have no idea how to do it, please help.

**Edit**

Ok, now i know that i can use cloud run for my backend and firebase for my frontend, can someone give me step by step procedure how to put my django files in cloudrun and firebase, and how to connect them, please

Answer (score 4):

Firebase Hosting only hosts static content, which means it doesn't run your Python/Django code. But you can run the code on Cloud Run, and then integrate that with Firebase Hosting. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run

Answer (score 0):

You can upload dynamic or static content on firebase, in the case of a Django app it's dynamic but your stylesheets / scripts are static content.

In `settings.py` you have to specify a route for your static files and store them in, like : `STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/static'`

Then in your server you have to specify that all the static files are stored in the above path.

Find more informations here : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/serving-static-files